# Material UI - font size in button label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to increase the font size of a label in my Material UI button in react.

I have a button setup:

import React from 'react';
import MyButton from '../materialui/Button.js';

```
const style = {
    background: '#FF5349',
    color: 'white',
    padding: '0 30px',
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  };


  const Start = () => (
      <span>

        <MyButton style={style} size="large">GET STARTED</MyButton>


    </span>

);

export default Start;
```

I can't find a way to add font-size to the styles property.

Other stack overflow posts suggest doing it as an inline style using the style property, but that overrides my const definition.

Comment: Looks like MyButton is your custom component. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to add `fontSize: '42px'` to your `styles` object (probably because you want to reuse this somewhere else?) you can just build a new one with the style added for your button:

```js
const Start = () => (
    <span>
        <MyButton style={{...style, fontSize: '42px'}} size="large">GET STARTED</MyButton>
    </span>
);
```

Comment: It doesn't recognise the fontSize property inside the style element (as in your example). I've just made 2 buttons so I can add the size to my const. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `myButton` in Material is the same of `RaisedButton` Anyway,

Button in Material-ui it's coming like `Div > Button > Div > Div > span`

So if you want to styling the button first of all you need to create a CSS class like

in your css file

This for styling button

```
.StylingButtonExample button{
   background-color: red;
}
```

This for styling the text inside the button

```
.StylingButtonExample button div div span{
  color: blue;
}
```

in react file

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

 <RaisedButton label="Default" className='StylingButtonExample' />
```

[image]

Hope this will help you and the others

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<MyButton />` Component is, in fact, the `<RaisedButton />` Component that material-ui offers, you can simply apply your label styling to the `labelStyle` property.

Therefore, if you wanted to change the font-size to `42px`, you could simply write it as follows:

`<MyButton labelStyle={{ fontSize: '42px' }}>GET STARTED</MyButton>`